# Add a second horizontal axis with different values in an Excel combo chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365

I have a combo chart (clustered column and line). They are currently using the same x-axis (which is simply the number of weeks, starting at 1) and different y-axes (primary one for the stacked column, secondary one for the line). So far so good.

Now I want to add a secondary horizontal axis, to be able to show the date in addition to the week number. This can be either a dummy graph, that I can set to be invisible, or use it for the line graph.

But is it actually possible to have a secondary x-axis with different values? In the "select data" window there is no possibility to add another set of x values... even with "secondary horizontal axis" enabled, there is only one set of x-data. ???

Any information about how to solve my problem is appreciated. I just want to have the calendar dates displayed on the x-axis in addition to the week number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of googling and trying out different possibilities, I managed to get different scales for the primary and secondary x-axis. It seems like a workaround though, since I had to create the chart all over again. Weird Excel.

It involved starting a new scatter plot, adding all the data series (with one of them having different x-axis values, in date format), and afterwards changing it to custom combo chart.